# Calling bash script from PHP fails, but it works locally

Tags: php, bash, ksh

I'm using PHP's shell_exec() to call a bash script, and I've identified the line that is is hanging up on:

I'm using [WinExe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe/) in that line, and the line that hangs up is this (sensitive values removed obviously):

```
result=`${LOCATION}/bin/winexe -U "user%password" //gateway "g:\\folder\\myscript.bat $1 $2"`
```

If I call this script from the terminal, it works perfectly fine, but if I call it from PHP, the web server hangs and doesn't come back to normal until I kill the processes using:

```
fuser -k -n tcp 80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved via:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6016750/270302

I basically use proc_open instead of shell_exec